# REST API returns 404

Tags: rest-api

I am using magento community edition 1.9.0.1. I try the REST Client Example explained here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html

But every time I send a request I got a 404

My server runs on localhost under the url : `http://localhost/magento/`

The rest api url I try is: `http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products`

For testing I am using the Firefox RESTClient Plugin.

What could be the reason for the error code 404?

**Solution:**

The reason for the 404 error message was a missing configuration in the apache2.con File (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf).

To enable rewrites it is necessary to add the option 'AllowOverride All'

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Be careful with the directory path in the Tag 'Directory'. The path must match the location of your Magento installation on the file system.
After changing the configuration restart the apache server.

Comment: Welcome to Magento! Please check this [great debugging tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429) and report back.

Comment: I tried this debugging options. But I still got 404.
Do you think that the URL pattern I am using is correct ? I have seen other patterns like this one: '/api.php?type=rest/products'. ?

Comment: Try it with 127.0.0.1

Comment: I have no luck. I edited my question and added a php test page which I use to test the rest api. Maybe you can you see a mistake in the script or in the error message I got when I run the script.

Comment: I have no clue about the api, but does your request hit php?

Comment: the reason was that my apache server was not configured correctly. I think there was a missing rewriting configuration. Now it seems to work. But I can't explain what exactly I have done. I try to figure it out....

Comment: I found the solution and added it into the question.

Comment: When the question is reopend, it would be great if you add the answer as solution

Comment: yes I would do so if the question will be reopened.

Comment: The solution mentioned in the question worked for me!